# Prove that $\text{tr}(B_1^{-1} B_2) \geq \text{tr}((A^\text{T} B_1 A)^{+} A^\text{T} B_2 A)$

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, positive-definite, trace, pseudoinverse

> Suppose that we have two real and positive definite $n \times n$ matrices $B_1$ and $B_2$ and that $A$ is an arbitrary real $n \times n$ matrix. Running some numerical tests by generating random matrices it seems that we have the inequality
> $$\text{tr}(B_1^{-1} B_2) \geq \text{tr}((A^\text{T} B_1 A)^{+} A^\text{T} B_2 A)$$
> with equality if $A$ is invertible. Here, tr denotes the trace, T matrix transposition, and $+$ the Moore-Penrose pseudo-inverse.

The equality part is straightforward using the inverse of a product and the cyclic invariance of the trace, but I don't know how to show the inequality part. Intuitively, I think it should hold, since we are essentially projecting $B_1$ and $B_2$ onto the image of $A$. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Proof.**

Let $Z := A^\top B_1 A$. Note that $Z^2$ is PSD.

First, we prove that, for all $t > 0$,
$$\mathrm{tr}(B_1^{-1}B_2)
> \mathrm{tr}\Big((Z^2 + tI)^{-1}Z \cdot A^\top B_2 A\Big). \tag{1}$$
(The proof is given at the end.)

Second, we use the property of the Moore-Penrose inverse
$$Y^{+} = \lim_{t\to 0^{+}} (Y^\mathsf{T} Y + tI)^{-1} Y^\mathsf{T}.$$
Taking limit of (1), we have
$$\mathrm{tr}(B_1^{-1}B_2) \ge \mathrm{tr}\Big((A^\top B_1 A)^{+} A^\top B_2 A\Big). $$

We are done.

$\phantom{2}$

---

*Proof of (1).*

(1) is written as
$$\mathrm{tr}(B_1^{-1}B_2)
> \mathrm{tr}\Big((Z^2 + tI)^{-1}Z A^\top B_1 \cdot B_1^{-1}B_2A\Big)  $$
or
$$\mathrm{tr}(B_1^{-1}B_2)
> \mathrm{tr}\Big((XA + tI)^{-1}X \cdot B_1^{-1}B_2A\Big) \tag{A1}  $$
where $X := A^\top B_1 AA^\top B_1$.

From $(XA + tI) X = XAX + tX = X(AX + tI)$, we have
$(XA + tI)^{-1}X = X(AX + tI)^{-1}$.
(A1) is written as
$$\mathrm{tr}(B_1^{-1}B_2)
> \mathrm{tr}\Big(X(AX + tI)^{-1} \cdot B_1^{-1}B_2A\Big)  $$
or
$$\mathrm{tr}(B_1^{-1}B_2)
> \mathrm{tr}\Big(AX(AX + tI)^{-1} \cdot B_1^{-1}B_2\Big)  $$
or
$$\mathrm{tr}(B_1^{-1}B_2)
> \mathrm{tr}\Big(B_1^{-1}B_2\Big) - \mathrm{tr}\Big(t(AX + tI)^{-1}\cdot B_1^{-1}B_2\Big)  $$
or
$$\mathrm{tr}(B_1^{-1}B_2)
> \mathrm{tr}\Big(B_1^{-1}B_2\Big) - \mathrm{tr}\Big(t(AA^\top B_1 AA^\top B_1 + tI)^{-1}\cdot B_1^{-1}B_2\Big)  $$
or
$$\mathrm{tr}\Big(t(AA^\top B_1 AA^\top B_1 + tI)^{-1}\cdot B_1^{-1}B_2\Big) > 0$$
or
$$\mathrm{tr}\Big(t(B_1AA^\top B_1 AA^\top B_1 + tB_1)^{-1}B_2\Big) > 0$$
which is true, using the fact that $\mathrm{tr}(YZ) > 0$ for two PD matrices $Y, Z$.

We are done.

Comment: You have a wide range of proving inequalities! +1

Comment: @TATAbox Thanks. Actually, not the case :) By the way, I have upvoted your two answers today which are tricky and nice.

Comment: Thank you. My current knowledge is not good enough to full understand your above proof also other aspect of inequality. I learnt so much  from you and solvers in MSE.

Comment: Wow, very nice proof! Thank you very much, that is extremely helpful.

Comment: @Andreas You are welcome.

Comment: @RiverLi Sorry if I annoy you. Could you please check the following inequality help me? $$6\ge \sqrt{2(a^3b+b^3c+c^3a)+3abc}+ab+bc+ca; \forall a,b,c\ge 0: a+b+c=3.$$
I saw that you deal with BW and can check correctness before.

Comment: @TATAbox It is true which is verified by Mathematica.

Comment: @RiverLi Thank you very much. I used BW without success. I'll open a topic in some days.

Comment: @RiverLi Now I see that BW helps well.